# onclick, Delete is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem whit my code but i cant find why it doesnt work.

I am creating an file delete link, with AJAX.

i know my delete page is working but my javascript doesnt go to it to delete the file.

Here is a part of my code.

formatoverzicht.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/website/libraries/jquery.js">
function deleteFileAjax(filename) { 
scriptitem = document.createElement('script');
scriptitem.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptitem.src = 'ajax.php?filename=' + filename;
scriptitem.id = 'ajax';
document.body.appendChild(scriptitem);
setTimeout('document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("ajax"))', 500);
}

</script>

<?php
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM format");
echo "<table border= 1><tr><td>Bestands naam</td><td>Groote</td><td>Laatst aangepast</td>         <td>Download</td><td>Verwijderen</td></tr>";

if (is_dir($dir)) {
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {          
        $filelocation = "uploads/". $file;

        $filesize2 = filesize($filelocation);

        if($filesize2 < '999'){
            $size = "Byte";
        }else if($filesize2 > '1000' &&  $filesize2 < '999999'){
            $size = "KB";
            $filesize = $filesize2 / 1000;
        }else if($filesize2 > '1000000' &&  $filesize2 < '999999999'){
            $size = "MB";
            $filesize = $filesize2 / 1000000;
        }else if($filesize2 > '1000000000' &&  $filesize2 < '999999999999'){
            $size = "GB";
            $filesize = $filesize2 / 1000000000;
        }
        $filesizeround = number_format((float)$filesize, 2, ',','');

        if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != "desktop.ini"){
            $lastedit = date("j-n-o H:i", filemtime($filelocation));

 $fileplace = "uploads/" .$file;

            echo "<tr><td>".$file."</td><td>".$filesizeround. " " .$size."</td>      <td>". $lastedit ."</td><td><a href='$fileplace' download='$file' '>Download</a></td><td>";
            ?> <button onclick="deleteFileAjax(<?php echo $file ?    >)">Delete</button></td></tr><?php
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
    }
}

?>
```

and ajax.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['filename'])) {
  if (unlink(htmlentities("uploads/". $_GET['filename']))) {
  echo "Great success!";
  }
}
?>
```

I hope someone can help me with the problem.

What i want is when you click on the link/button that the file gets deleted without a refresh. if this is with an confirm or with out doesnt really matter.

Thanks for the help atleast.

Comment: Delete with a GET request is a BAD BAD BAD idea.

Comment: I don't understand. So how the "DELETE is not defined" relevant?

Comment: I'm in the same boat as @OfirBaruch, I don't see any variable named "delete"

Comment: i have tryd evrything, but the only error i get is the deleteFileAjax is not defined. so i think there is something wrong somewhere but i cant find it. and i think becouse of that it wont delete the file.

Comment: Frankly speaking, your snippet features a lot of bad practices: including jQuery and writing raw js [to perform an homebrew JSONP request]; mixing mysql with [invalid] html, with business logic and with intrusive js; using a GET to perform a DELETE. My sincere advice is to learn web development the right way, instead of hotfixing an unmaintainable pile of code.

Comment: i am a starting programmer with just 1 year of school done so i most of this is new for me. but im working to get my codes better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using Ajax. What you are doing is loading another file into the body of your file, then removing it, which is a bad idea. You should look at [jQuery's Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). An example of what you want to do would be:

```
function deleteFileAjax(filename) {
    $.ajax(function() {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: { filename: $(this).data("file") },
        success: function() {
            alert("File deleted");
        }
    });
}
```

You also have an error with your button:

```
<button onclick="deleteFileAjax(<?php echo $file ?    >)">
```

should be

```
<button onclick="deleteFileAjax('<?php echo $file ?>');">#
```

In addition, you shouldn't include code in the same `<script>` tag you include a file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/website/libraries/jquery.js">
    function deleteFileAjax(filename) { 
        scriptitem = document.createElement('script');
        scriptitem.type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptitem.src = 'ajax.php?filename=' + filename;
        scriptitem.id = 'ajax';
        document.body.appendChild(scriptitem);
        setTimeout('document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("ajax"))', 500);
    }

</script>
```

Needs to be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/website/libraries/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteFileAjax(filename, buttonId) { 
        scriptitem = document.createElement('script');
        scriptitem.type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptitem.src = 'ajax.php?filename=' + filename;
        scriptitem.id = 'ajax';
        document.body.appendChild(scriptitem);
        setTimeout('document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("ajax"))', 500);
    }
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE**

To make the file disappear after a successful delete you will need to make some changes. Firstly the code that echo's out the button:

```
<button data-file="<?php echo $file ?>" class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
```

Second the JavaScript:

```
$('.delete-btn').click(function() {
    $.ajax(function() {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: { filename: filename },
        success: function(return) {
            if(return == 'SUCCESS') {
                $this = $(this).closest('tr');
                $this.remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Finally the page that does the deleting:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['filename'])) {
  if (unlink(htmlentities("uploads/". $_POST['filename']))) {
  echo "SUCCESS";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: aha, but i still have the problen whit the deleteFileAjax is not defined. i cant find the solution for that part.

Comment: @user3182383 I've updated my answer to solve that for you too.

Comment: i get this:Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html. But i dont know why this is, is it becouse im trying to delete an image or something.

Comment: @user3182383 That's probably for your jquery library. Make sure that it's uploaded and you're pointing to the right place for it. If you try to browse to the jquery library in your browser what do you get?

Comment: when i do that i get the complete jquery.js file as text.

Comment: @user3182383 The error should tell you which file it is having a problem with. However as long as it can find the jquery file it shouldn't stop your Ajax request from working.

Comment: it is deleting the files now, but only after a refresh. so your answer helped alot atleast. Thanks for it.

Comment: @Yorin if you want it to remove it from the page, then you need to modify the `success` function. I've adjusted it above to something that may work, though you might need to adjust it a little. You also need to adjust the button.

Answer (score 1):

When you are debugging JavaScript errors, you should always look at the rendered source

```
onclick="deleteFileAjax(<?php echo $file ?    >)"
```

will render as

```
onclick="deleteFileAjax(MYFILE)"
```

so do you have a variable MYFILE? No, it is supposed to be a string so it needs quotes

```
onclick="deleteFileAjax('<?php echo $file ?>')"
                        ^                   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to warp `'` `deleteFileAjax('<?php echo $file; ?>')`  in button

```
 <button onclick="deleteFileAjax('<?php echo $file; ?>')">Delete</button>
```

instead of

```
  <button onclick="deleteFileAjax(<?php echo $file ?    >)">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<button type="button" onClick="deleteFileAjax('<?php echo $file; ?>')">Delete</button>
```